# how to get sum of array in vue js using computed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

> this the resul of my query

```
{1: {deduction: 625}, 2: {deduction: 500}, 3: {deduction: 2500}, grandTotal: 8460, otTotal: 50,…}
1: {deduction: 625}
2: {deduction: 500}
3: {deduction: 2500}
allowance: 0
grandTotal: 8460
otTotal: 50
```

> my computed in vue  I got an error here `"TypeError: this.grand.reduce is not a function"`

```
totaldeduct(){
return this.grand.reduce((acc, item)=>{
return acc+ Number(item.deduction)
},0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce() is an array function in javascript. You either want to use forEach for your object or rewrite it to an array.

```js
const data = [
      { deduction: 625 },
      { deduction: 500 },
      { deduction: 2500 },
      { grandTotal: 8460 },
      { otTotal: 50 },
    ];

    function totaldeduct(data) {
      return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
        if(item.deduction)
          return acc + item.deduction;
        else return acc
      }, 0);
    }

    let reduced = totaldeduct(data);

    console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: I want only get the total of `deduction` ?

Comment: I gave you already the answer, it shouldn't be hard as JS dev, to rewrite it.
`if(item.deduction) return acc + item.deduction; else return acc`

Comment: Sorry bro I am a begginer

Comment: not working bro.. I think bcause its an object how can I convert it into array?

Comment: I got it bro..!